# Error: Couldn't find any stories in your Storybook, Please check your stories field of your main.js config

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Hello for some reasons the storybook is throwing
[storybook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCYZE.png)
all i did was update my package using npm update and now it is throwing the following error.
While in console section is see the following error VM121 vendors~main.iframe.bundle.js:25791 Unexpected error while loading ./components/identBox/identBox.stories.tsx: Cannot access 'module' before initialization
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'module' before initialization
at Module. (http://localhost:9001/main.iframe.bundle.js:1892:37)
at ./src/components/identBox/identBox.stories.tsx (http://localhost:9001/main.iframe.bundle.js:2018:30)
at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:9001/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:857:31)

my package.json is

```
{
  "name": "bla bla bla",
  "title": "bla bla bla ",
  "version": "2.0.3",
  "homepage": "bla bla ",
  "description": "Legitimates users in the checkout and community workflow.",
  "license": "private",
  "browsers": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "author": "2020+ Team Jedi;2022+ Team Sith",
  "maintainers": [
    "bla bal "
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "bla bla "
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "contributors": [],
  "bugs": {},
  "sideEffects": false,
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run storybook",
    "start": "npm run storybook",
    "build": "npm run rollup",
    "test": "set CI=true && react-scripts test",
    "test:watch": "react-scripts test",
    "test:coverage": "set CI=true && react-scripts test --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9001 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -o public/storybook",
    "rollup": "rollup -c",
    "rollup:watch": "rollup -cw",
    "sonar-scanner": "sonar-scanner",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .jsx,.js,.ts,.tsx src",
    "update-readme": "projectz compile"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.stories.tsx",
      "!src/**/index.ts"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^22.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-image": "^2.1.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^4.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-backgrounds": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-controls": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-jest": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-notes": "^5.3.21",
    "@storybook/addon-queryparams": "^6.2.9",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.2.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/theming": "^6.5.9",
    "@svgr/rollup": "^5.4.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "12.12.11",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.4",
    "@types/react-html-parser": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/retry": "^0.12.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.4.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.38.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.38.0",
    "acorn": "^7.2.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "husky": "^4.0.3",
    "jest-each": "^26.6.2",
    "mockdate": "^2.0.5",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.27",
    "postcss-discard-comments": "^6.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "projectz": "^2.18.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-docgen-typescript-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.14.0",
    "react-testing-library": "^8.0.1",
    "rollup": "^2.75.7",
    "rollup-plugin-analyzer": "^4.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-graph": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-scss": "^3.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-size-snapshot": "^0.12.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.32.1",
    "rollup-plugin-visualizer": "^5.6.0",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "typescript": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bank-ident-component": "1.0.49",
    "date-holidays": "^1.5.1",
    "id-card-check-component": "1.0.60",
    "jawa-error-boundary": "^1.1.4",
    "mh-env-utils": "^2.0.1",
    "mh-tracking": "^8.0.8",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "retry": "^0.12.0",
    "sessionstorage-facade": "0.0.4",
    "sith-frontend-utils": "^5.0.6",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "vip-component": "^1.0.91"
  }
}
```

storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-viewport',
    '@storybook/addon-backgrounds',
    '@storybook/addon-a11y',
    {
      name: '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
      options: {
        tsDocgenLoaderOptions: {},
      },
    },
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-docs',
      options: {
        configureJSX: true,
        sourceLoaderOptions: null, // this fixed the import error, see https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6974
      },
    },
    '@storybook/addon-queryparams',
  ],
}
```

Storybooks / preview.js looks like
preview.js

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { addDecorator, addParameters } from '@storybook/react'
import { withA11y } from '@storybook/addon-a11y'
import * as mhc from 'mh-components'
import { theme } from 'mh-components/dist/cjs/theme/Provider'
require('./styling.css')
window.MHGlobals = { frontendUrl: 'https://www.telekom.de/magenta-zuhause/kundencenter' }

addDecorator(withA11y)
addParameters({
  viewport: {
    defaultViewport: 'desktop',
    viewports: {
      ...{
        mobile: {
          name: 'Magentahaus Mobile',
          styles: {
            width: '320px',
            height: '568px',
          },
        },
        tablet: {
          name: 'Magentahaus Tablet',
          styles: {
            width: '768px',
            height: '1024px',
          },
        },
        desktop: {
          name: 'Magentahaus Desktop',
          styles: {
            width: '1366px',
            height: '768px',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
addParameters({
  backgrounds: {
    default: 'white',
    values: [
      { name: 'lightgrey', value: '#eeeeee', default: false },
      { name: 'white', value: '#ffffff', default: true },
    ],
  },
})
addDecorator((Story) => <Story />) // Hack so that i can use hooks in stories

addDecorator((story) => (
  <mhc.Provider theme={{ ...theme, frontendUrl: 'bla blba bla/magenta-zuhause/kundencenter/assets/' }}>
    <>
      {story()}
      <mhc.DisplayNotifications />
      <mhc.GlobalStyle />
    </>
  </mhc.Provider>
))
```